# fileupload with Formdata ajax and busboy

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I would like to upload files with ajax using the html5 file API, but I've troubles saving the file on the serverside ( node.js )

I'm using busboy but busboy doesn't trigger a file event, just a field event.

clientside:

```
upload.prototype.sendFile = function(fileData){
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('test.jpg',fileData)
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("post", "/file/upload", true);
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

serverside:

```
app.post('/file/upload',function(req,res,next){
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
    file.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
    });
    file.on('end', function() {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
    });
  });
  busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
  });
  busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Done parsing form!');
    res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
    res.end();
  });
  req.pipe(busboy);
})
```

Comment: I passed in a DataURL object which doesn't work, mscdex pointed out that you need a file or blob object.

Comment: If the only thing you're adding to your `FormData` instance is the single `'test.jpg' => fileData`, then why not simply send just the `fileData` without putting it inside a `FormData` instance? Then you can avoid having to parse multipart/formdata.